# How to get the Latitude and Longitude on Map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

How can I get the Latitude and Longitude values of a particular location that I have long clicked on the map in Android?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the long click, I suggest you check out http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2010/handling-longpresslongclick-in-mapactivity/. This will go into detail on how to listen for long click events within the Maps API since there is little or no built-in functionality that I know of.

As for the lat/lng code, after you get the long click you can translate the pixels to coordinates.

```
public void recieveLongClick(MotionEvent ev)
{
    Projection p = mapView.getProjection();
    GeoPoint geoPoint = p.fromPixels((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
    // You can now pull lat/lng from geoPoint
}
```

Comment: The link in this answer points to a blog post I wrote a while back. I just wrote a new post with a solution that is cleaner and works better. It might be of interest: http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2011/android-handling-longpresslongclick-on-map-revisited/

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to manage the LongClick event, and then use the code to find out longitude and latitude with the following code:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint=mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
int latitude = geoPoint.getLatitudeE6();
int longitude = geoPoint.getLongitudeE6();
```

where 'event' is the object of 'MotionEvent'.

Use any other event according to your case.

Answer (score 0):

It gives latitude and longitude on which point of map click

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            //myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

              //The code below demonstrate how to convert between LatLng and Location

              //Convert LatLng to Location
              Location location = new Location("Test");
              location.setLatitude(point.latitude);
              location.setLongitude(point.longitude);
              location.setTime(new Date().getTime()); //Set time as current Date
              txtinfo.setText(location.toString());

              //Convert Location to LatLng
              LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(newLatLng)
                       .title(newLatLng.toString());

              map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    });
```