# Returning a GeoPoint on user touch MapView Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to return a GeoPoint with the longitude and latitude of the location the user just touched.  I have seen and read tons or examples that display the longitude and latitude in a toast by overriding `dispatchTouchEvent()`. 
I believe this won't work for my case for the following reason.

I want the user to be able click a button that will then call another method that will return a geopoint on the user's next tap. So, in short, a geopoint is only returned on the tap after the user clicks the button.

The only work around I can see using the `dispatchTouchEvent()` is the following.

If the button has been clicked, write to the shared preferences. Then in `dispatchTouchEvent()` check to see if the button has been clicked. If it has not been clicked,do nothing. If it has been clicked write the longitude and latitude to shared preferences and then read them from shared preferences and create a GeoPoint out of them in a different method.

I don't feel like that is a very elegant idea. I feel like there should be a much cleaner way of doing this(like somehow returning just a geopoint)

I hope this makes a little bit of sense.  I'll try to answer any questions I can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446811/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-on-map-in-android/4446910#4446910)

Comment: This looks promising, unfortunately I do not have time tonight to implement it. I will let you know what happens tomorrow! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read the title of your question..so pardon me if put the wrong answer..:D

```
    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GeoPoint p = null;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY());
                mapBackButton.setText(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + ","
                        + p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 + "Action is : "
                        + event.getAction());
                return true;
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()
                                / 1E6 + "Action is : " + event.getAction(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to figure out a way to actually return the GeoPoint instead of just displaying a toast. I have a work around using a methodology similar to yours, just trying to find a more elegant way.  Read my post if you want more information on what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 and  p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6 are actually the geopoints...
you can use them any where.