# Visible Geopoints within phone screen

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, markers

I am displaying some marker on map. i want to find out the visible geopoints(markers) within phone screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to add marker on geo point location. [See this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/11/display-marker-on-mapview-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you want to put marker on map after touch some certain area:

[Returning a GeoPoint on user touch MapView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975862/returning-a-geopoint-on-user-touch-mapview-android/7976012#7976012)