# Google Map longitude and latitude from particular place

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I have a Android GPS enabled mobile. 
It gives me, my current place location on map with Latitude, Longitude.

Now I want something like that when I show places on Google map.
How can I find that places longitude and latitude. How can i do this ?

Comment: Something [like this](http://www.getlatlon.com/)? if yes have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4446910/593709)

Comment: What you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reverse-geocoding is the process of translating latitude longitude coordinates to a human-readable address.**

The Geocoder api does that , there might be as sample of this in andriod project.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html